# URDF Link Mesh File Locations

Tags: urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it true that the mesh files for URDF links must reside on each machine using the robot? For example, the mesh files for turtlebot must reside both on the netbook and the workstation running rviz. If this is true I think this fact should be added here [http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Link#preview) under the mesh heading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12844/urdf-link-mesh-file-locations/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that is true. The mesh information is never communicated in any message (AFAIK), rather just the filename (using the package syntax) is communicated.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-01**:
That would be very helpful.

**Comment by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on 2012-02-01**:
Should I add it to the wiki because it's not completely clear?